# How do I set up mail delivery for a contact form in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, actionmailer

I'm trying to build a contact form using the approach I saw in the [Railscast about ActiveAttr](http://railscasts.com/episodes/326-activeattr?view=asciicast) (which gives me a Message model that isn't backed by a database).

This code is in the controller for Messages:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @message = Message.new
  end

  def create
   @message = Message.new(params[:message])
   if @message.valid?
     # TODO send message here
     redirect_to root_url, notice: "Message sent! Thank you for contacting us."
   else
     render "new"
   end
  end
end
```

I don't know what kind of code I need to write in order for the contact form input (the message) to be sent to a specific email address during the `create` action. Would someone please give me a general overview of what I need to know or need to set up in order to make this work? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add something like this.

```
def create
  @message = Message.new(params[:message])
  if @message.valid?
    UserMailer.send_message(@message).deliver
    redirect_to whatever_path, notice: "Message sent."
  else
    render "new"
  end
end
```

You will need to create a Mailer. It's pretty easy and Rails already has a great guide on how to do this. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Create a mailer

`rails generate mailer UserMailer`

Then in your UserMailer `app\mailers\user_mailer.rb`

```
def send_message(message)
  @message = message
  email = "myemail@example.com"
  mail to: email, subject: "You have received a message"
end
```

Then create your email view `app\views\user_mailer.txt.erb`

```
You have a new message

Your message says

<%= @message.whatever_attribute %>
```

Comment: Yes thanks, but my question is about the code in the controller's create action. :-)

Comment: Just added a link to the Rails mailer guide. :)

Comment: Thanks! Guide mostly seems to talk about sending emails to other users through the app, but what about emailing form input to myself? That's what I'm stuck on...

Comment: You still need a mailer to send the email but you can then just add your own email in your mailer method so in the create action you could have something like `UserMailer.send_message(@message).deliver` and in your mailer method you would have `mail to: "myemail@whatever.com", subject: "You've received mail"`

Comment: I've updated my answer to more of a step by step of what you need to do